# How to create GUID for multiple resources in Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am currently generating ARM template for a Log Analytics workspace saved search. Each query should have a unique GUID, but I can generate a single unique GUID in the parameter for a given module. However, I would like to assign a different GUID to each query.

Is there is any to generate multiple GUIDs inside ARM Template?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate them using guid() ARM Template function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string?tabs=json#guid).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "Utc": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[utcNow('u')]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "This is not an optional parameter, please do not pass a new datetime"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "user": {
            "user-name": "Test Person"
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "guid1": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[guid(concat(parameters('Utc'), '1'))]"
        },
        "guid2": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[guid(concat(parameters('Utc'), '2'))]"
        }
    }
}
```